# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo java.lang.NullPointerException when get from Datepicker

Tags: android, datepicker

Why my code doesn't work with error null pointer exception,

This is my code

```
public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        final Calendar kal = Calendar.getInstance();
        tahun = kal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        bulan = kal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        tanggal = kal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
       tampilkan_tanggal();

    }
```

And, this is my log

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                         Process: com.example.client18.dd, PID: 6306
>                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.client18.dd/com.example.client18.dd.signup_activity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
>                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:116)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
>                             at com.example.client18.dd.signup_activity.(signup_activity.java:28)
>                             at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>                             at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
>                             at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1064)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
>                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>       Application terminated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537150/android-activity-nullpointerexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-compon

Comment: `at com.example.client18.dd.signup_activity.(signup_activity.java:28)`... Please mention what line that is. Your error is there

Answer (score 0):

@[denny-kurniawan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6381761/denny-kurniawan),
Generally speaking, a null pointer boils down to using an object that is empty of what you are expecting it to contain. Utilize try/catch whenever possible. Step through the debugger. In the case of your example, try this:

```
    public void onStart(){
     try {
      super.onStart();
      final Calendar kal = Calendar.getInstance();
      tahun = kal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      bulan = kal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
      tanggal = kal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
      tampilkan_tanggal();
     } catch (Exception ex) {
     // do something here to see the stack trace 
     System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Success!");
    }
```

Put your breakpoint on the Calendar kal line.